# how capable are mysql stored functions

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project and I'm running into some bottlenecks querying my database. It's for an internal search engine where I have a table of words and a table for occurrences. The occurrences have an auto ID, a wordID, and the parentID, in this case, the pageID that they came from, and a occurrence count.

I'm running into a bottle neck in my php by taking the chatter, breaking it into an array of words, and for every word...
- check to see if the word is already indexed
- - if it isn't, I add the index and return the ID
- check if there is already an occurrence
- - if there isn't, I add one
- - if there is, I incriment the count

I'm currently looking into adding this into mysql as a stored procedure, but how much of this is something that mysql could do? so far in the examples, all I've seen are ways to do queries and format the output, nothing too advanced. I'd need to likely send the function an array and let it do multiple queries. I'd also need to loop through the array. I've be searching but haven't found this capability yet. Is this something I should be able to do? Can anyone point me to some resources or examples?

Comment: You're asking for massive amounts of trouble if you go down this road. First, that's not really the sort of thing stored procedures and triggers are ideal for. Secondly, MySQL has a full-text search index feature built-in, so it's not clear why you're writing your own.

Comment: It's for fine control over what I'm searching and the ability to quickly add or remove items from the search. for example, an article is saved in a "draft state", I don't want it to be searchable.

Comment: You can do that with a full-text index/ Just add an additional `WHERE` clause, like `published=1`.